# codigo nodemailer para office365 dejo de funcionar

Tags: nodemailer, office365

gracias de antemano a esta gran comunidad.

resulta que tengo codigo en mi servidor nodejs(v12) para enviar email por smtp a traves de una cuenta office365 que ha estado funcionando sin problema hasta ahora.

he probado actualizando nodemailer a la ultima version (6.6.1) y sigo obteniendo el mismo error de conexion rechazada.

este es el error:

Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.office365.com
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) `{ errno: 'EREFUSED', code: 'EDNS', syscall: 'queryA', hostname: 'smtp.office365.com', command: 'CONN' }`

y este es el codigo:

```
var mailConfig = {
                host : 'smtp.office365.com',
                port : '587',
                secure : false,
                auth : {
                    type: 'login',
                    user : user,
                    pass : pass
                }   
            };

            var email = {
                from: from,
                to : mail,
                subject : subject,
                html : message
            };

            
            var creatransport = nodemailer.createTransport(mailConfig);
            creatransport.sendMail(email, function(error){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }else{
                    var solicitud = new Solicitudpassword();
                    solicitud.abonadoid = cliente._id;
                    solicitud.email = mail;
                    solicitud.save();
                    return res.status(200).send({message: 'mail enviado correctamente'});
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

me autorespondo, tras muchos quebraderos de cabeza, resulta que alguien en mi organizacion habia desabilitado el acceso en microsoft Azure (nadie sabe nada, ni ha tocado nada, como siempre) y por tanto dejó de aceptar las peticiones de mi aplicacion.

despues de investigar, encontrar el problema y habilitar de nuevo el acceso, el codigo vuelve a funcionar correctamente como antes, asi que en realidad no hay problema con el codigo, y por tanto se puede cerrar la pregunta si se considera oportuno.